# Correct way to define array of enums in JSON schema

Tags: arrays, json, enums, jsonschema

I want to describe with JSON schema array, which should consist of zero or more predefined values. To make it simple, let's have these possible values: `one`, `two` and `three`.

Correct arrays (should pass validation):

```
[]
["one", "one"]
["one", "three"]
```

Incorrect:

```
["four"]
```

Now, I know the `"enum"` property should be used, but I can't find relevant information where to put it.

Option A (under `"items"`):

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
}
```

Option B:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "enum": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

Comment: **Docs**: [Enumerated Values](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html?highlight=enum#enumerated-values)

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Option A is correct and satisfy your requirements.

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
}
```

Update 20231108: type can be omitted. According to last json-schema specifications, `The enum keyword is used to restrict a value to a fixed set of values. It must be an array with at least one element, where each element is unique.` and `You can use enum even without a type, to accept values of different types.`

Comment: You can omit the `"type": "string"`. Emum applies values "as is", so no need to define type

Comment: Your are right. Added to the answer

Answer (score 30):

According to `json-schema` [documentation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#tuple-validation), the enumerated values of an `array` must be included in the `"items"` field:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
}
```

If you have an `array` that can hold e.g. items of different type, then your schema should look like the one below:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["one", "two", "three"]
    },
    {
      "type": "integer",
      "enum": [1, 2, 3]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That second example doesn't allow the array to contain two different types. It is tuple validation[1], which constrains the first and second items in the array to match the first and second schemas in the "items" array. 
[1] https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#tuple-validation

Comment: I think the proper construct to use in the second example is probably `anyOf`: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#anyof

Comment: @GrahamLea I think you're right in earlier drafts (including the latest when you wrote your comment!) ... and I believe that as of the 2020-12 draft, to avoid this source of confusion, to specify tuples (in this example [string,int]), one now uses "prefixItems" instead of "items", which makes it easier not to get this wrong, and to see the difference between "any element may be a string or an int" and "the first item must be a string, the second must be an int")!

"An array in which each element must be either a specified integer enum, or a specified string enum" is still slightly tricky ...

Comment: Mixed values are defined very easy with enums. You just need to define them "as is" - including complex nested objects/arrays/null. You dont need to spefiy datatypes or to use `anyOf`. This can be as simple as
`"enum": ["one", "two", "three", 1, 2, 3, null, ["internal", "array"], {"internal": "object"}]`
More info in [official docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/enum)