# How do I set the allowed values without repeating myself?

Tags: arrays, json, validation

I want my JSON schema to accept a list but the values in the list are from a set list and can apparear in any order!

I.e. `["GOV","CRD", "CON"]` is acceptable, but so is `["CRD", "GOV", "COM"]`.

My current thinking is something along these lines:

```
"sources":{"type": "array",
           "uniqueItems": true,
           "emum": ["CRD", "GOV", "COM", "CON", "OTH", "UTL", "PRO", "TEL", "POS", "INS", "CCJ", "POP", "VOT", "MVR", "PPS", "DRV", "PMC"]},
```

But I'm not entirely sure that's going to do what I want. I've read up on `items` where you can define the values in the list, but it looks like that would set the order and also the number of items in the list. Although both can be worked around using `oneOf` combined with definitions.

E.g. (shortened for space saving reasons) Please feel free to correct this if I'm wrong:

```
{
  "definitions": {
      "source":{"emum": ["CRD", "GOV", "COM", "CON", "OTH", "UTL", "PRO", "TEL", "POS", "INS", "CCJ", "POP", "VOT", "MVR", "PPS", "DRV", "PMC", ""]},
  }
  "sources":{"type": "array",
             "uniqueItems": true,
             "items": {
                     "source": {"$ref": "#/definitions/source"},
                     "source": {"$ref": "#/definitions/source"},
                     "source": {"$ref": "#/definitions/source"},
                    .
                    .
                    .
             }
  }
}
```

**My question is: Is there a nicer way to do this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to define array of enums in JSON schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924271/correct-way-to-define-array-of-enums-in-json-schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify every possible order. When the array is made limited by `enum`, the items can come in any order. However, you have to specify the type of the enumerated values.

```
"sources":{
           "type": "array",
           "uniqueItems": true,
           "items": {
              "type": "string",
              "emum": ["CRD", "GOV", "COM"]
           }
```